# php symfony 1.4 custom validator error

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, custom-validators

Here's my problem: I'm trying to write a custom validator in symfony.

usage :

```
$this->setValidator('path', new sfValidatorFile(array(

    'required'   => false,
    'path'       => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir'),
    'mime_types' => 'web_images',
    'validated_file_class' => 'sfImageTransform')));
}
```

validator :

```
<?php class sfImageTransform extends sfValidatedFile{

  public function save($file = null, $fileMode = 0666, $create = true, $dirMode = 0777) {


   $saved = parent::save($file, $fileMode, $create, $dirMode);

       $img = new sfImage(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/'.$saved, 'image/jpeg');
       $img->resize(500,400);
       $img->save();

       return $saved;
  }
} ?>
```

I'm getting this error: `Fatal error: Class 'sfImageTransform' not found in /http/htdocs/pizza_propel/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/validator/sfValidatorFile.class.php on line 167`

Here's the part that's going to make me murder the first Sensio Lab employee I'll ever meet:
Whenever I remove the `<?php ?>` brackets from validator file, i get this `class sfImageTransform extends sfValidatedFile{ public function save($file = null, $fileMode = 0666, $create = true, $dirMode = 0777) { // let the parent class save the file and do what it normally does $saved = parent::save($file, $fileMode, $create, $dirMode); //echo $saved;die; $img = new sfImage(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/'.$saved, 'image/jpeg'); $img->resize(500,400); $img->save(); //$saved->resize(1000,null); // //$saved->resize(1000,null)->overlay(new sfImage('logo.png'), 'bottom-right'); return $saved; } } Fatal error: Class 'sfImageTransform' not found in /http/htdocs/pizza_propel/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/validator/sfValidatorFile.class.php on line 167` in my browser window, (as expected), but after putting them back and refreshing, it executes exactly ONCE, does what it should do, and at the next attempt it does the same shthing again. Seriously... what the fhell? I'm raging over this for over an hour, and I'm about to smash everything smashable in 75 mile radius. Anyone dealt with this before?

Comment: where is your class ? in the lib directory ? how do you named the file ?

Comment: thanks for your comment, but i just solved it :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And so once again I get to answer my own question. I should really stop bother asking.

It seems, that by a pangalactically idiotic coincidence, the named of the validator class file  came into conflict with some other file, or something like that. Renaming the validator class file resolved the problem.